# Open a “Setting” page after Chrome extension is installed first time by using .crx file in extension for private enterprise chrome application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

Upon installation of the chrome plug-in by using .crx file in extension , I want to show a settings page for the first time only. The following fields will need to be filled in:

```
1)TID(textbox)
2)SID(textbox)
3)TLocation(textbox) 
4)BaseURL(for web service API)
```

This data will be stored and user can change this setting in future as well.

**How I can show this page upon installation by using .crx file, this app will be private app only.**

Currently I am using webview to show the our website in the chrome app like below:

```
<webview src="http://yoursite.com/chromeapp" style="width:100%; height:90%"></webview>
```

I have search over the google and found below methods but it is not working on .crx installation,I think this will work for public app only

```
  chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (object) {
  chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://yoursite.com/"}, function (tab) {
    console.log("New tab launched with http://yoursite.com/");
   });
 });
```

**My JS File Code :**

```
 chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  runApp();
 });


 chrome.app.runtime.onRestarted.addListener(function() {
  runApp();
  });

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (object) {
  chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://yoursite.com/setting.html"}, function (tab) 
  {
    console.log("called: http://yoursite.com/setting.html");
  });
  });

  function runApp() {
       chrome.app.window.create('browser.html', {
          bounds: {
          'width': 1024,
          'height': 768
         }
         });
       }
```

Please help if anybody has done such type of work.

Comment: `chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener` should be good. What do you mean it's not working?

Comment: Always webview page http://yoursite.com/chromeapp is showing on first time open  but http://yoursite.com/setting.html is not showing by calling method on chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener, this method will work on .crx file installation in chrome extension?

Comment: I want to show http://yoursite.com/setting.html page on first open of the application. after that app should work as it is working by using webview URL  http://yoursite.com/chromeapp . please help

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code it will definitely work for your scenario.

**Background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (details) {
  if (details.reason == "install") {
    runSettingApp();
  } else {
    runApp();
    }
});
```

Create two functions. First will open the setting screen on  first install and 2nd for open the home page on launch.

```
function runApp() {
chrome.app.window.create('home.html', {
bounds: {
  'width': 1024,
  'height': 768
  }
 });
}

function runSettingApp() {
chrome.app.window.create('setting.html', {
bounds: {
  'width': 1024,
  'height': 768
 }

 });
}
```